# States Storyboards Animation in Expression Blend

Tags: silverlight, expression-blend, visualstatemanager, visualstates

What I am trying to do is learn how to animate various controls in Silverlight using Expression Blend.

I've started with trying to animate a listbox. I have a listbox whose Style I have tried to edit (Edit Style ->Edit Current/Edit Copy) which brings up the states panel with various default states.

What I am unable to figure out is how to link a state from the default list of states that shows up to a storyboard animation using only Expression blend. 
[image]

So for example if I have a list of Music Albums where only the album name is displayed and on selecting it I want the selected list item to grow a bit in size so as to accomodate more details about the album... like artist name, release date, etc.

Does anyone have any links that will explain how to achieve the above in a step by step way?.. or atleast some thing on how to go about learning the basics in the correct manner.

Thanks

Comment: Please elaborate on what you mean by linking states? Btw I found the Microsoft Toolbox tutorials to be great: http://www.microsoft.com/design/toolbox/school/

Comment: Im not sure if I am asking the right question. Im pretty new to this. I was under the impression that you create an animation by using storyboards and play that animation when a particular event like mouse over occurs.  A good example of what I want to do would be similar to the animation in the course view in the link you gave. Ive modified my question a bit.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you can link that storyboard to a state after making it separately, but the way to create timelines for states is to click on a state, when it will turn recording mode on and the timeline edits you make then will be automatically linked to that state.

Comment: thats the thing I thought too. But somehow its not working the way I want. For eg. in mouseover state when I am in record mode, I change the properties to blurview. But the change is instant. It doesnt transition into that blurview like I thought it would. I've set the duration to 5 seconds....hey whats the storyboard for then?